# Can I use azure functionapp storage account for other purposes like storing files in blob storage?

Tags: azure, function, blob, storage, account

Can I use azure function app storage account for other purposes like storing files in blob storage? If yes will it according to Microsoft guidelines and also will it cause any performance issue? Specially when size of blob storage get increased to GBs?

I am near to production, so please come up with any suggestions, best practices, solutions as soon as possible.

Comment: If you are asking for help, you might want to be a bit more specific on what you need, rather than asking for general help, also, doing a bit a research would help as well, demanding help isn't going to help you win friends. try : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-decide-blobs-files-disks

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use azure function app storage account for other purposes like
>   storing files in blob storage?

Yes, you can.

> If yes will it according to Microsoft guidelines and also will it
>   cause any performance issue? Specially when size of blob storage get
>   increased to GBs?

It depends. Each Azure Storage account has some [`pre-defined throughput limits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account). As long as you stay within those limits, you should be fine.

---

Having said this, ideally you should have a separate storage account. Considering creation of storage account doesn't cost you anything till the time you do some transactions in it, you may be better off creating a separate account to store data required by your application.